# remove plugin admin menu in wordpress without installing plugin in v3.8.1

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu

I follow instruction on this page to remove some admin menus: [`remove_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)

But is seems it only works on default admin menus. Admin menu added by plugins is not getting removed.

For example, I tried removing admin menu of wordpress seo by yoast using

```
remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard' );
```

But the menu remains there. All other standard WordPress admin menus were removed except Yoast SEO.

Any idea how can I also remove admin menu of plugins?

I saw some similar questions but the recommended codes doesn't seem to be 3.8.1 compatible so I added this question to start a new fresh question specific to 3.8.1

Comment: You must ensure to call `remove_menu_page` *after* the page is added. Do you know which hook WP Seo by Yoast is using to add the menu page? When you find it, use same hook with a lower priority.

Comment: How will I know the hook?

Comment: Search the source code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_wpseo_admin_menu_links');

function remove_wpseo_admin_menu_links(){

remove_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpseo_admin_bar_menu', 95 );

remove_menu_page( 'wpseo_dashboard' );


}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it. So, for me to get rid of several plugin admin menu, I have to look for their hook and use remove action? What if I have five admin menu to remove, I have to search for all of their hooks? Is there no way to ad action that will eliminate it regardless. Or perhaps a reverse way, to force WP admin to show only specified admin menu ad disregard anything not specified on the function. This is one down anyway. Thanks for the answer  [edit] sorry i do not have enough rep yet to vote up.

Comment: Depends. Which menu links specifically?

Comment: Thanks.. Perhaps I will just contact the author since the plugins are premium ones.

Comment: is there no way to call the function that remove the links after all pages has been called? making sure that it will be included when remove function is called?