# remove_menu_page doesn't work on custom plugin menus

Tags: admin-menu

Using the [`remove_menu_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) function works for removing the default admin menu items by their slug like so:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_menu' );

function hide_menu() {
    remove_menu_page( 'index.php' ); // Dashboard
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); // Tools
}
```

When a plugin created their own menu in the Dashboard, the URL structure looks like the following:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=plugin-slug
```

However when trying to remove the custom plugin menu item like so:

```
remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=plugin-slug' );
```

Nothing changes. Looking at a similar questions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/169934/98212) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/132210/98212), it seems that my function isn't called in time once the custom plugin settings load? Yet, when I try to increase the priority to a higher number, that still doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_menu', 9001, 1 );
```

Is there a work around? Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Decrease the priority.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to the answer that [the_dramatist](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/44192) posted, it was a matter of just hooking to the [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) tag. The slugs for those plugin pages can be retrieved by the debug script that the_dramatist provided, or you can simply look at that query value after `admin.php?page=plugin-slug`:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_243070_hide_menu' );

function wpse_243070_hide_menu() {
    remove_menu_page( 'index.php' ); // Dashboard
    remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); // Tools
    remove_menu_page( 'plugin-slug' ); // Some plugin
    remove_menu_page( 'another_slug' ); // Another plugin
}
```

Comment: That is right, simple use remove_menu_page( 'menu_slug'). it does work well.

Comment: Have you checked your logs? By doing this, sometimes you will get a PHP warning stating that there is an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() as documented here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page under Usage.

Comment: To fix the php warning issue, you should use the `admin_menu` hook instead of the `admin_init`

Comment: @PabloSGPacheco Thanks for fix, I updated it in my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Place this below temporary code in your `functions.php` or any where that can be executed.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'the_dramatist_debug_admin_menu' );

function the_dramatist_debug_admin_menu() {

    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $GLOBALS[ 'menu' ], TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
```

Then search for the `plugin-slug`. In which array you find it copy the `[2]` value and put it in `remove_menu_page('the [2] value')` and hook it to `admin_init` like below-

```
add_action('admin_init', '');
function the_dramatist_remove_menu(){
    remove_menu_page( 'the [2] value' );
});
```

And it will be working. And after it is working remove the temporary code block.

On the other hand, you can inspect the plugin code which menu page you wanna remove and in their `add_menu_page()` function take the fourth parameter of the `add_menu_page()` function and put it inside `remove_menu_page('fourth parameter')`. It will work as well. The code will look like below-

```
add_action('admin_init', '');
function the_dramatist_remove_menu(){
    remove_menu_page( 'fourth parameter of add_menu_page()' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looking at your answer, I've actually figured out that if I hook to the `admin_init` tag, I'm able to hide the custom setting menus. See my answer.

Comment: +1 for the print_r Globals snippit

Comment: I was getting php warnings with `admin_init`. To fix that, I've used the `admin_menu` hook

Comment: My two cents for the_dramatist_debug_admin_menu : as admin menu is still there, you need to move print_r results on the right to see everything : echo '<pre style="margin-left: 180px;">'.....

Answer (score 1):

For me simple unsetting of menu elements proved to be the easiest and most versatile approach, this way you can for instance remove all menu items but leave only some desired like so:

```
add_filter('admin_menu', 'wpse_243070_hide_menu_items', 100);

function wpse_243070_hide_menu_items() {
  foreach ($GLOBALS['menu'] as $mkey => $mval) {
    if (!in_array($mval[2], [
                  'separator1',
                  'separator2',
                  'profile.php',
                  'edit.php?post_type=my_custom_post'
        ])) {
      unset($GLOBALS['menu'][$mkey]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any reasons for the downvote? It's the only way I can think of for removing all menu items but some chosen. It's also the only way that I know that works for removing some menu items created by plugins like ACF since the above approach didn't work.